# Is there any open data-set for sentence segmentation?

Tags: nlp, text

I am working on textual analysis of reports in English language. The documents are official records. I requires the sentence level segmentation of text. One way is through regular expression. Other way is through classifier trained on tagged data-set and then predict whether a period is sentence boundary or not? But for that i will require tagged data-set. Is there any sentence boundary tagged data-set freely available?

Answer (score 3):

Some Corpora in the [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html) have a method `sents()` that returns each sentence as a list of words, for example the Brown corpus:

```
import nltk
nltk.download() # this opens a GUI to download all corpora needed
from nltk.corpus import brown
sentences = brown.sents()
```

Answer (score 3):

The [British National Corpus](http://ota.ox.ac.uk/desc/2554), "a 100 million word collection of samples of written and spoken language from a wide range of sources", is free of charge and [segmented](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/docs/URG/cdifbase.html#cdifcomp), but i never used it.